# LUKS full disk encryption use keyfile instead of passphrase

Tags: linux, centos, unix, encryption, luks

I have enabled LUKS full disk encryption on an LVM volume while installing centos6.6, however it asks for a passphrase every time the OS is rebooted.

I am now trying to use a key file according to [this post](https://www.howtoforge.com/automatically-unlock-luks-encrypted-drives-with-a-keyfile).  Unfortunately it does not work...and still asks for the passphrase.

```
/etc/cryptab

sda2 /dev/disk/by-uuid/0e7815c0-0941-431a-a6d2-cbe78132d292 /root/keyfile luks
```

Any ideas of a better solution to remove the passphrase and use only the keyfile?

Comment: You can't use a key file to unlock the root filesystem, only non-root filesystems.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Really ?

Comment: @MichaelHampton wrong!

Answer (score 2):

Did you regenerate the initramfs ?

The initramfs is a small file system called before your rootfs to ask for your password and decrypt the LUKS container and handle stuff. It contains the /etc/cryptab file to be able to know what it should uncrypt / mount.

If you haven't regenerate it, the initramfs don't have you modified file and can't handle your new configuration.

So try to update the initramfs. Here some help for Red Hat : http://advancelinux.blogspot.ch/2013/06/how-to-rebuild-initrd-or-initramfs-in.html

Keep in mind that your key file have not to be on the encrypted partition, and so the encryption become useless because it easy to find the key.